# 18.04 new install screen freezes

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

I have a new 18.04 install, when I try to use the software method to power off it just hangs. I have to hold down the power switch until it powers off. Is there a fix for this? I was recommended the alt-prtscn RESUIB which works better than the hard power down.
Currently very little installed as I want to figure out the bugs prior to a full set up. If things go wrong i just keep doing a full reinstall until I can get it.

Update: Once I was able to get Ubuntu installed, I did not make any modifications to grub. This new reinstall seems worse than the first time. The keyboard still works to a point.

Update: during install I select to download 3rd party stuff. This makes me set a password. Then upon the final restart there is a blue screen with some options. This is all new to me. I just let it boot, should I choose something else.

Comment: Try sudo poweroff in terminal.

Comment: Once it freezes I cannot always get terminal to work. I can try this but I have freezing issue on top of this issue.

Comment: Once it freezes I cannot always get terminal to work. I can try this but I have freezing issue on top of this issue. Sudo power off does not shut the machine down.  I can see the background and webpage in the terminal window. Alt+prtscn+sub restarts machine but not shut it down.